# point of inflection for discontinuous function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a doubt on graph of $f(x) = \frac{x-5}{x+6}$. 
Is there a point of inflection on $x=-6$?
The graph changes it nature from concave up to concave down but $f''(x)$ is not equal to zero anywhere.

Comment: $x = -6$ is not in the domain of $f$ so it cannot be considered as a point of inflection.

Comment: Yeah that's true. But as per the definition of point of inflection the concativity changes so isn't that be a point of inflection? will there be any other point of inflection for this graph?

Comment: there is none !

Comment: Concavity is opposite on *disjoint* intervals. There is no inflection point, nor is one required to exist.

Comment: If a graph is defined for x>=0 so can x=0 have a relative maxima or minima?

Comment: @DeepSea If I define the function this way: $f(x) = \frac{x-5}{x+6}$ for $x \neq -6$, $0$ for $x = -6$. May I now consider $x=-6$, a point of inflection?

Answer (score 2):

There won't be any point of inflection as at x = -6 the function is undefined.