# Inflection point definition for discontinuous functions

Tags: derivatives, continuity

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044523/point-of-inflection-for-discontinuous-function) question, what if we define the function at $x = -6$ and let $f(-6)$ be zero ?

Similar question would be:
Is $x=0$ a point of inflection for the curve
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{x}&\text{if}\, x\neq 0\\
 0&\text{if}\, x=0\
\end{cases}$$

Because i can clearly see it changing concavity at $0$. Why does it need to be continous ?

Comment: Which definition of inflection point are you using?

Comment: By definition, an inflection point is a point on a _curve_ and a curve is a _manifold_, but your example does not constitute a manifold at the given point.

Comment: @Dan isnt there just the standard definition of inflection point ? ( I am using the wikipedia defn )